# Why does a Site-Scoped Feature need to be installed on farm-level?

Tags: feature, site, server-farm

"Feature with Id '#########################' is not installed in this farm and cannot be added to scope"

I received this error when trying to deploy a SharePoint 2010 solution in VS 2010. The problem is that the web parts in the Feature are all site-scoped. This solution was deployed on another server with site-scoped web parts and the feature not present as a farm feature. So, why is it asking me to install the feature on the farm if the feature is site-scoped? If I need to, how do I install the feature to the site farm? Should I deploy with Management Shell or a script instead of VS (if that might be causing the issue?)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a difference between solution installation and feature activation.
Installing solution to farm means to copy .wsp file to farm, unpack it, copy files to destination folders and make ready for features activating.
Feature activation prepare it for real using.

For more information see [Installation and Deployment of a Farm Solution in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544500(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your method, you trying to activate a feature which is not installed yet that's why you are getting the above error.

You can deploy the solution via VS and install it then may be activate using the powershell.
check this for more info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/04/02/server-error-feature-guid-is-not-installed-in-this-farm-and-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope.aspx

Also please check this one, may be it feature guid mismatch in feature.template.xml file

http://markviky.blogspot.com/2010/09/error-while-activating-feature.html

Comment: Now that I look at my script....yep, I don't have an "Install-SPFeature" command at all. And I think Visual Studio doesn't bother adding the feature before trying to activate it.